# Django rest framework - how can i limit requests to an API endpoint?

Tags: python, django

I created an API using Django Rest Framework, now i'm working on a rate limiting system, to avoid spam. The built-in throttling system works great, and i managed to add multiple throttles:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        # 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        #     "xapi.authentication_backends.TokenBackend",
        # ),
        'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
            'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
        ],
        'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
            'anon': '70/minute',
            'user': '70/minute',
            'user_sec': '2/second',
            'user_min': '120/minute',
            'user_hour': '7200/hour',
        },
        
        'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        )
    }
```

And in my `views.py`:

```
class UserSecThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'user_sec'

class UserMinThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'user_min'

class UserHourThrottle(UserRateThrottle):
    scope = 'user_hour'
```

So if some user performs more than 120 queries in a minute, that user will be blocked for a minute, if the hour limit is breached, the user is blocked for one hour. Is there some way to decide for how much is a user blocked? For example, if i want to block someone for 10 minutes if they perform more than 120 queries in a minute. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a custom throttle, override `BaseThrottle` and implement `.allow_request(self, request, view)`. The method should return `True` if the request should be allowed, and `False` otherwise.

Optionally you may also override the `.wait()` method. If implemented, `.wait()` should return a recommended number of seconds to wait before attempting the next request, or None. The `.wait()` method will only be called if `.allow_request()` has previously returned `False`.

If the `.wait()` method is implemented and the request is throttled, then a Retry-After header will be included in the response.

```
import random
class CustomThrottle(throttling.BaseThrottle):
    def allow_request(self, request, view):
         """
         Return `True` if the request should be allowed, `False` otherwise.
         """
         return random.randint(1, 10) != 1

    def wait(self):
        """
        Optionally, return a recommended number of seconds to wait before
        the next request.
        """
        cu_second = 600
        return cu_second

class UserSecThrottle(CustomThrottle,UserRateThrottle):   # or AnonRateThrottle
    scope = 'user_sec'

class ExampleView(APIView):
    throttle_classes = [UserSecThrottle]
    .......
```

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/#custom-throttles

Comment: Thank you a lot! So in my case, once i defined the custom throttle, i need to call the custtom throttle in my class, like class `UserSecThrottle(CustomThrottle):` instead of `UserSecThrottle(CustomThrottle):`?

Comment: @Sumithran I still have to clarify where to import the custom throttle, that's why i asked

Comment: @JayK23 Hello jayK Recheck my answer. I edited it.It fully worked for me..

Comment: Hello, I did exactly as you explained and still got 60 seconds to wait (I changed 600 to 1800 in case it was miliseconds but it was not the problem)